# How to order SelectItems in custom renderer extending MyFaces HtmlMenuRenderer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, selectonemenu

I´m trying to migrate a custom component to render a SelectOneMenu over MyFaces 2.0, I need to use this library because WAS 8.5 was moved from Mojarra 1.2 to MyFaces 2.0 implementation.

In mojarra 1.2, I extended from `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer` which had a method `renderOptions` which receives as parameters this `FacesContext context, UIComponent component, List<SelectItem> listSelectItems`, but now with MyFaces I haven´t a similar method.

This is the method that I used to order items before to render (Mojarra 1.2):

```
@Override
protected void renderOptions(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        List<SelectItem> listSelectItems) throws IOException {

    COBISSelectOneMenuUIComponent uicomponent = (COBISSelectOneMenuUIComponent) component;


    String order = uicomponent.getOrder();

    if (order == null || order.isEmpty()) {
        order = DEFAULT_ORDER;
    }

    if (order.equals("asc")) {
        Collections.sort(listSelectItems, comparatorSelectItemLabel);
    } else {
        if (order.equals("desc")) {
            Collections.sort(listSelectItems,
                    comparatorSelectItemLabelInvers);
        }
    }

    super.renderOptions(context, uicomponent, listSelectItems);
}
```

And now whit MyFaces I dont find the way to order the SelectItems before to render them.

I try to build the SelectOneMenu with MyFaces using this code for the component (The relevant parts):

```
package cobiscorp.cobis.ce.components.jsf;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectItems;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu;

@FacesComponent(value=COBISSelectOneMenuComponent.COMPONENT_TYPE)
public class COBISSelectOneMenuComponent extends HtmlSelectOneMenu {

    /** 
     * Component family of {@link COBISSelectOneMenuComponent}. 
     * */
    public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "COBISSelectOneMenuComponent";
    /** 
     * Component type of {@link COBISSelectOneMenuComponent}. 
     * */
    public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "COBISSelectOneMenuComponent";

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return COBISSelectOneMenuComponent.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    public static final String ATTR_ORDER = "order";
    public static final String ATTR_ORDER_DEFAULT = "asc";

    public String getOrder() {
        return (String) getStateHelper().eval(ATTR_ORDER, ATTR_ORDER_DEFAULT);
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        getStateHelper().put(ATTR_ORDER, order);
    }

}
```

And the render is this (The relevant parts):

```
package cobiscorp.cobis.ce.components.render;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectItems;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectOne;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.render.FacesRenderer;

import org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlMenuRenderer;
import org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils;

import cobiscorp.cobis.ce.components.jsf.COBISSelectOneMenuComponent;
import cobiscorp.cobis.ce.domains.ICOBISConstants;
import cobiscorp.cobis.ce.util.ComparatorUIComponentItemASC;
import cobiscorp.cobis.ce.util.ComparatorUIComponentItemDESC;

@FacesRenderer(componentFamily = COBISSelectOneMenuComponent.COMPONENT_FAMILY, rendererType = COBISSelectOneMenuRenderer.RENDERER_TYPE)
public class COBISSelectOneMenuRenderer extends HtmlMenuRenderer {

    /** 
     * Renderer type of {@link COBISSelectOneMenuRenderer}. 
     * */
    public static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "cobiscorp.cobis.ce.components.COBISSelectOneMenuRenderer";


    /**
     * El atributo comparatorSelectItemLabelASC tiene como finalidad comparar los
     * select item por los label en orden ascendente
     */
    private ComparatorUIComponentItemASC comparatorSelectItemLabelASC;
    /**
     * El atributo comparatorSelectItemLabelDESC tiene como finalidad comparar
     * los select item por los label en orden descendente
     */
    private ComparatorUIComponentItemDESC comparatorSelectItemLabelDESC;

    /**
     * Este constructor inicializa los comparadores
     */ 
    private Boolean loadDefaultOption = null;

    public COBISSelectOneMenuRenderer() {
        comparatorSelectItemLabelASC = new ComparatorUIComponentItemASC();
        comparatorSelectItemLabelDESC = new ComparatorUIComponentItemDESC();        
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer#encodeBegin(javax.faces
     * .context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent)
     */
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
            throws IOException {

        COBISSelectOneMenuComponent uicomponent = (COBISSelectOneMenuComponent) component;

        loadDefaultOption = uicomponent.getLoadDefaultOption();
        if(loadDefaultOption){
            List<SelectItem> listItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(1);
            listItems.add(new SelectItem("", ""));

            UISelectItems uiSelectItems = new UISelectItems();
            uiSelectItems.setValue(listItems);

            uicomponent.addSelectItemsDefault(uiSelectItems);   
        }

        super.encodeBegin(context, uicomponent);
    }

    protected void renderMenu(FacesContext context,
            UISelectOne selectOne, boolean disabled, Converter converter)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("renderMenu");

        COBISSelectOneMenuComponent uicomponent = (COBISSelectOneMenuComponent) selectOne;

        String order = uicomponent.getOrder();

        uicomponent.getChildren();

        List selectItemList = RendererUtils.getSelectItemList(
                (UISelectOne) uicomponent, context);

        System.out.println("renderMenu order -> " + order);

        if (order.equals("asc")) {          
            Collections.sort(selectItemList, comparatorSelectItemLabelASC);
        } else {
            if (order.equals("desc")) {
                Collections.sort(selectItemList,
                        comparatorSelectItemLabelDESC);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer#encodeEnd(javax.faces
     * .context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent)
     */
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
            throws IOException {

        Boolean autocomplete = null;
        String id = null;

        COBISSelectOneMenuComponent uicomponent = (COBISSelectOneMenuComponent) component;

        this.renderMenu(context, uicomponent, isDisabled(context, uicomponent), getConverter(context, uicomponent));

        super.encodeEnd(context, component);

        if (context != null) {
            ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
            if (component.isRendered() && uicomponent.isDisabled() == false) {
                autocomplete = uicomponent.getAutocomplete();
                id = uicomponent.getId().trim();

                if (autocomplete != null && autocomplete.equals("true")) {
                    writer.startElement("script", component);
                    writer.writeAttribute("type", "text/javascript", "type");
                    writer.writeText(String.format(
                            ICOBISConstants.SCRIPT_DHTML_LIST, id, uicomponent
                                    .getClientId(context)), null);
                    writer.endElement("script");
                }
            }
        }   

    }


}
```

Whit the previous code the component is render without order, this is a sample the component code in xhtml page:

```
            <cobis:selectOneMenu idForm="form_cita_uno" order="asc">

                <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="C"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="A"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="F" itemValue="F"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="D" itemValue="D"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="N" itemValue="N"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="L" itemValue="L"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Z" itemValue="Z"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="X" itemValue="Z"></f:selectItem>

            </cobis:selectOneMenu>
```

Could give me ideas about how to order items with version 2 of MyFaces?

Comment: Why don't you sort the model in the model side?

Comment: Because the project already exists and has many Beans and many Models and therefore would be too much work having to modify all these Beans. This is a migration from WAS 7 to WAS 8.5 and the preexisting custom SelectOneMenu component was ordered "asc" by default

Comment: A decent IDE has very good search/replace/refactoring tools. Should not be to difficult

Comment: Of course, but I'm trying to avoid modifications to the project code java by SCM issues, and because I want the migration is as transparent as possible (only replace the custom component's jar :))